# which lambda has more chances to be inlined

Tags: c++, c++14

The way I see it, if the lambda has to store state, it will likely not be inlined. If it doesn't store state, then it's like a simple free function, and there's more chances that it's gonna be inlined.

Does the **standard** say anything about it?

```
class Window {public:int value = 5;};

class SomeClass:
{
public:
    Window *w;

    void DoSomething()
    {
         auto error = [&](int n)
         {
             std::cout << (w->value  * 5);
             return w->value * n;
         };

         auto error  = [](Window *w, int n)
         {
             std::cout << (w->value  * 5);
             return w->value * n;
         };

         error(w, 7);
         error(7);
         // ...

         error(w, 10);
         error(10);

    }
}
```

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I asked if the standard say anything about it. As far as I know the standard doesn't rely on different compilers.

Comment: If your compiler has problems inlining either, file a bug.

Comment: "*Does the standard say anything about it?*" No, it doesn't. Inlining functions that aren't declared `inline` is totally implementation dependent (and even inlining `inline` functions is still implementation dependent, though at least the standard acknowledges the possibility for `inline` functions).

Comment: While I readily confess to not having a clue what the standard says about this, there are two separate things here: the lambda function, which for all intents and purposes can be inlined independently of how much state the lambda carries, and the state, which is stored separately of the function anyway. So the only thing that should matter to the choice of inlining or not, is related to the function itself, and the usual considerations (function size, number of callers) apply.

Comment: @Cornstalks: C++ doesn't really acknowledge the possibility for inlining. The `inline` keyword is actually more of a linker directive than anything else.

Comment: @IInspectable: The standard definitely acknowledges the possibility for inlining `inline` functions. It's also possible for functions to be inlined in the compiler (before the linker ever sees them).

Comment: I should correct my original comment, though, because it turns out that the closure's function operator is declared `inline` (see section 5.1.2, paragraph 5). But that said, the standard doesn't say either one is more likely than the other to be inlined.

Comment: @T.C. You were a bit right http://ideone.com/UaJG7Y that was my actual problem it seems (it was inside my lambda making it too long to be inlined) even tho it should have not generated any code at all. I'm guessing its a VS bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone that has spent much of my spare time the past couple of years writing a compiler to go on top of LLVM, I'm pretty sure any decent compiler will inline both of these - if not, I'd raise a bug with whoever makes the compiler that doesn't.

The stuff in `[...]` will just be an extra argument (a "closure argument"), which typically turns into a pointer to a structure [which can be "unpicked" into regular arguments when/if the function is inlined].

The main reason that a simple small function is NOT inlined is that it's called through a function pointer, including the vtable. A non-static [at a global level] function may also be produced in the non-inline version, since the compiler can't determine that the function is not called elsewhere.

Of course, LARGE functions may not get inlined because the compiler thinks it is a waste of space to do so, but gcc for example will inline very large functions when they are known to becalled from only one place.

I would also argue that there is no difference in how the compiler inlines lambda to other functions - aside possibly from the fact that they obviously can't be called from anywhere else [unless the lambda is passed out of the function where it is declared as a std::function or similar - but it can't be inlined either way].

If you REALLY care, then check the compiler output.

Comment: I have spent the last 30 minutes trying to figure out the issue. http://ideone.com/UaJG7Y This issue made my lambda body function too long to get inlined in release mode. Any ideas about that behaviour? Or it's simply a visual studio bug I should report?

Comment: `va_arg` functions can't be inlined. Although the spec may not say so, I've yet to see a compiler that deals with that. This is because with variable number of arguments, the arguments are passed on the stack [in the typical case], and it will typically not be possible to inline the correct stack-cleanup.

Comment: (I tell a lie - I have seen our OpenCL compiler at work inline printf - but that was not a good thing by any means, as it meant compile time grows to "very long" when you call printf a dozen times in the same piece of code, as inlining the ~3000 lines of printf several times is not particularly good for compiler performance)

Comment: But printf has a body. Mine doesn't (it always returns the same and doesn't use the parameters) I thought the compiler should be smart enough to not generate any code.

Comment: It still needs to take an arbitrary number of parameters, and apparently the compiler doesn't bother to check that it's NEVER CALLED and thus remove it [or it relies on the linker to remove dead functions]

Comment: Interestingly, it seems like both gcc and clang does indeed remove this function completely - presumably because the effect of its call is known and there is no side-effect from it. Since the typical use of va_arg functions is to actually use the argument, I guess that's why I don't see that getting inlined...